# Exponential of upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function, exponentiation, matrix-exponential

Consider the matrix
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\0&a\end{matrix}\right),\qquad 
A^n=\left(\begin{matrix}a^n&b(na^{n-1})\\0&a^n\end{matrix}\right)
$$
The exponential series is
$$
\exp(X)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}X^k
$$

Thus take the formal exponential of $A$ I get
$$
\exp(A)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\left(\begin{matrix}a^k&b(ka^{k-1})\\0&a^k\end{matrix}\right)
$$
Since $ka^{k-1}$ is just the derivative of $a^k$, and $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$, I get
$$\tag{*}
\exp(A)=\left(\begin{matrix}e^a&be^a\\0&e^a\end{matrix}\right)
=e^a\left(\begin{matrix}1&b\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)
$$

An easier computation that gives some consistency would be
$$
\begin{align}
\exp\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\0&a\end{matrix}\right)
&=\exp\left[\left(\begin{matrix}a&0\\0&a\end{matrix}\right)
+\left(\begin{matrix}0&b\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)\right]\\
&=\exp\left(\begin{matrix}a&0\\0&a\end{matrix}\right)\exp \left(\begin{matrix}0&b\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)
=\left(\begin{matrix}e^a&0\\0&e^a\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}1&b\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)
\end{align}
$$
since in exponential expansion of the second factor only the first two terms are relevant.

> (Q1) Makes this computation any sense?
> Is it generalisable for the Jordan normal form?
>
> (Q2) If we look at
> $$
> A=\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\0&a\end{matrix}\right)
> =\left(\begin{matrix}a&0\\0&a\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}1&b/a\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)
> $$
> makes the following any sense, or can we extract anything interesting from it?
> $$
> e^a\left(\begin{matrix}1&b\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)
> =\exp A = \left(\begin{matrix}e^a&0\\0&e^a\end{matrix}\right)^{\left(\begin{matrix}1&b/a\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)}
> $$

Comment: @bof It's an error from mine. I corrected it

Answer (score 1):

(Q1), yes this makes sense, since $\left(\begin{matrix}a&0\\0&a\end{matrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{matrix}0&b\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)$ commute.

(Q2),  $\left(\begin{matrix}e^a&0\\0&e^a\end{matrix}\right)^{\left(\begin{matrix}1&b/a\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)}$ makes no sense.